# conda init powershell does not work vscode windows 10

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to launch my conda virtual environment from vscode powershell terminal. The powershell terminal has been responsive to a few conda commands like `conda env list` but when I tried to run `conda init powershell` it throws an error below :

````
conda-script.py: error: argument command: invalid choice: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\conda-script.py' (choose from 'info', 'help', 'list', 'search', 'create', 'install', 'update', 'upgrade', 'remove', 'uninstall', 'config', 'clean', 'package')```
````

Comment: What is the Conda version? IIRC, `conda init` was introduced in v4.6.

Comment: Can you find `init` in `conda --help`? Agree with merv, `init` was added after v4.6.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `conda 4.10.3` and no such error is shown. Please update `conda` and see if the error goes away:

```
conda update conda
conda update conda-build
```

Answer (score 0):

I was too struggling with this trouble for a long time but couldn't find any solution online.
But I found it at last.
This is occurring because Windows PowerShell is not allowed to run local PowerShell scripts. It can be enabled in developer settings.

On windows 10

```
Settings > Update & Security > For developers >  Enable PowerShell to run local PowerShell scripts without signing in.
```

See where to enable:

[image]